# Unable to use startActivityForResult within widget class

Tags: android

Im still new to this android stuff but I am trying to write a widget.  I got all the code I needed working in a stand alone app but am now trying to get it to function as a widget.  But I am having some problem starting the contact picker intent.

Basically,  what I would like to do is launch the contact picker intent when a widget is created,  but that simple code  is not working for me and Im not sure what is wrong with it.  Here is the slice of code...

```
    public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider 
{ 
  ....

  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) 
  { //User is creating a new widget.
    //Select a contact.
    int contact_pick = 1;
    //Contact Picker
    Intent PickContact = new Intent(
      Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
      ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI
    );
    startActivityForResult(PickContact, contact_pick);
  }

  ....
}
```

eclipse just gives the following message for the startactivity line: The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type 
 WidgetProvider

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`startActivityForResult()` is only available on `Activity`. You cannot pick a contact from an `AppWidgetProvider`. However, you can start a regular `Activity`, using `startActivity()`, and it can then use `startActivityForResult()` to pick a contact.

Comment: This got me back on track... Thank you!  I created a new class and now call the class.

Answer (score 0):

First, a little nitpicking: you should not use upper case for your variables, call your picker pickContact, not PickContact.

Second, your message tells your undefined for the type WidgetProvider. WidgetProvider, your class, extends [AppWidgetProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html), however unless I am mistaken, AppWidgetProvider lacks startActivityForResult. Hence, the message, you are not calling the method from the class you should be calling it from...

Comment: can you clarify on the nitpicking?  Why the need to use lowercase on the first letter of a variable?

Comment: Because it's the Java standard, and it makes it easier to read for your fellow Java developers. It's not necessary per se, but you will find it useful later on, when your codebase grows. You COULD write classes with lowercase names and variables in allcaps, but your code would soon be unreadable, imagine if you use a mix of static methods and chaining, as in objectUsed.Method(classname.STATICMETHOD())... already is hard to read with only two calls :D